# Excel QueryTable Parameters do not bind Sql Parameters

Tags: sql, excel, parameters

I'm new in Excel development and I have an issue that It's driving me crazy. I hope you can help me.
Let me explain the situation, 
I'm trying to create a QueryTable to import data from SQL , but ... I get an error at the moment to refresh the QueryTable, 
the error message indicates that I'm not passing values for required parameters. ( It works hard coded :[ )

After many hours of investigation, I wasn't able to find a solution or an example to guide me...  And here I am :|
I don't know what I'm doing wrong,  Here is some code

```
foreach (Range row in main.Rows)
    {
            //row.Clear();
            rowID = row.Row;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(getAccounts(rowID, columnID)) )  
                continue;

            /*  string connectionString = // \"
                    string.Format("OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}",
             */      

            //string sql = "EXECUTE [Funciones].[Cuenta_Saldo_Anho] ?,?";
            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTipoSaldo.Text)) sql +=  ",?";

           string sql = "{CALL [Funciones].[Cuenta_Saldo_Anho] (?, ?";
           sql += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTipoSaldo.Text))? "" : ", ?" + ")}"; // optional parameter

           var qt = wSheet.QueryTables.Add( connectionString, row.Cells , sql);
           qt.CommandType = XlCmdType.xlCmdSql;

           var ctas = qt.Parameters.Add("@ctas", XlParameterDataType.xlParamTypeLongVarChar);
           //ctas.SetParam(XlParameterType.xlConstant, cuentas);
           ctas.SetParam(XlParameterType.xlRange, wSheet.Cells[rowID, columnID]));
           ctas.RefreshOnChange = true;

           qt.Parameters.Add("@anho", XlParameterDataType.xlParamTypeInteger)
 .SetParam(XlParameterType.xlConstant, Int32.Parse(anho));

           qt.Parameters.Add("@tipoSaldo", XlParameterDataType.xlParamTypeVarChar)
 .SetParam(XlParameterType.xlConstant, txtTipoSaldo.Text);

            //qt.BackgroundQuery = true;
            qt.FieldNames = false;
            qt.AdjustColumnWidth = false;
            qt.RefreshOnFileOpen = false;
            qt.Refresh();
      }
```

Any help is welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: Since you are putting the sql string together for each row, why don't you hard-code the values? `sql = "{CALL [Funciones].[Cuenta_Saldo_Anho] (" + wSheet.Cells[rowID, columnID] + ", " + anho + ", '" + txtTipoSaldo.Text + "')"`